# Issues in overwriting the send event of UIApplication in Swift programming

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I was able to trigger the send event method in **UIApplication** by using the code below.But the send event method is triggered twice instead once for a single touch event.This works properly in Objective C facing this issue after converting to **swift**. Can anyone tell me the issue in the below code.

---

**main.swift**

```
UIApplicationMain(C_ARGC, C_ARGV, NSStringFromClass(MainApplication), NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate))
```

---

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
    class MainApplication: UIApplication{
override func sendEvent(event: UIEvent)
{
    super.sendEvent(event)
    if(event.type == UIEventType.Touches)
    {
        NSLog("send event")}}}
```

---

Comment: Please note the change I made to your title, the previous was not appropriate. Negative voting has a meaning behind it, it means there is a problem with the question or you have not met the requirements

Comment: Yeah, i rectified it.Do you have answer for my question

Comment: Use of unresolved identifier 'UIApplicationMain' shows error in main.swift. Any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue but a little bit of investigating the apple developer site and I learned that the UITouch event has a [Touch Phase](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITouch_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UITouchPhase) constant. In your code, you are checking for touches only. sendEvent is fired once for each phase of the touch, the NSLog statement is being invoked for the touchesBegan and touchesEnded phases. Change code to check for either touches Began or touches Ended.