# How to catch all events in Swift without breaking other event handlers

Tags: swift, uikit, swift5

How can I catch any touch up event in my application view without affecting any other event in subview or subview of the subview?

Currently whenever I add UILongPressGestureRecognizer to my root view, all other `addTarget` functions break in subviews and their subviews.

```
func gestureRecognizer(_: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
   return true
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
   let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))
   button.setTitle("Click me", for: .normal)
   button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClick), for: .touchDown)
   self.view.addSubview(button)
        
   initLongTapGesture() // This kills the button click handler.
}

func initLongTapGesture () {
   let globalTap = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapHandler))
   globalTap.delegate = self
   globalTap.minimumPressDuration = 0
   self.view.addGestureRecognizer(globalTap)
}

@objc func tapHandler(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
   if ([.ended, .cancelled, .failed].contains(gesture.state)) {
      print("Detect global touch end / up")
   }
}

@objc func buttonClick() {
   print("CLICK") // Does not work when initLongTapGesture() is enabled
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate solution to allow the long press gesture to work without preventing buttons from working is to add the following line:

```
globalTap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
```

in the `initLongTapGesture` function. With that in place you don't need the gesture delegate method (which didn't solve the issue anyway).

---

The big question is why are you setting a "long" press gesture to have a minimum press duration of 0?

If your goal is to monitor all events in the app then you should override the `UIApplication` method `sendEvent`. See the following for details on how to subclass `UIApplication` and override `sendEvent`:

[Issues in overwriting the send event of UIApplication in Swift programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27564121/issues-in-overwriting-the-send-event-of-uiapplication-in-swift-programming)

You can also go through these search results:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D%5Bswift%5D+override+UIApplication+sendEvent

---

Another option for monitoring all touches in a given view controller or view is to override the various `touches...` methods from `UIResponder` such as `touchesBegan`, `touchesEnded`, etc. You can override these in a view controller class, for example, to track various touch events happening within that view controller.

---

Unrelated but it is standard to use the `.touchUpInside` event instead of the `touchDown` event when handing button events.

Comment: Wow... Thank you for a throughout answer, the immediate solution worked! Didn't realize that cancelsTouchesInView was enabled by default.  To answer the "big" question, my app is far more complex than this piece of code that I pasted and I have a lot of different events along with pan etc... I am using long press gesture with duration of 0 to catch states of touch down , hold down and release. I am not trying to monitor events, I just wanted to set some flags when global touch up happens. I am also aware of the touchUpInside standard :)

Comment: I just updated my answer with one more option that may be better than using the long press gesture.